# Copy Assignment Operator vs Move Assignment Operator

Tags: c++

I just have a question regarding the runtime of the copy assignment operator and the move assignment operator. I would expect the move assignment operator to run much faster, but I found that they run at exactly the same speed (more or less).

This is leading me to believe that I did something incorrect or that I'm copying data where I shouldn't be. If someone could shed some light on this, I would appreciate it.

Copy Assignment Operator (runtime is 1.235s):

```
w3::DArray2d& w3::DArray2d::operator=(w3::DArray2d& rhs){

    // std::cout << "assignment operator" << std::endl;

    if ( this != &rhs )
    {   

        delete [] array;

        array = new double*[rhs.columns];

        for (int i=0; i < rhs.columns; i++){
            array[i] = new double[rhs.rows];
        }


        this->rows = rhs.rows;
        this->columns = rhs.columns;

        // std::cout << this->rows << std::endl;
        // std::cout << this->columns << std::endl;

        for(int a = 0; a < rhs.rows; a++){
            for(int b = 0; b < rhs.columns; b++){
                array[a][b] = rhs.array[a][b];
            }
        }
    }

    return *this;

}
```

Move Assignment Operator (runtime 1.233s):

```
w3::DArray2d& w3::DArray2d::operator=(w3::DArray2d::DArray2d&& rhs){

    if(this != &rhs){
          rows = std::move(rhs.rows);
          columns = std::move(rhs.columns);
          array = std::move(rhs.array);

          // reset rhs
          rhs.rows = 0;
          rhs.columns = 0;
          rhs.array = nullptr;
      }
      return *this;

}
```

This is the runtime of a 5000x5000 2d array filled with random values from 0.00 to 1.00 using the current time as the seed.

This is how I calculated time:

```
#define TIME(start, end) double((end) - (start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC

        std::clock_t cs, ce;

        cs = std::clock();
        a = std::move(b);
        ce = std::clock();
        std::cout << "Move Assignment " << TIME(cs, ce) << " seconds";
        std::cout << " - a.check = " << a.check();
        std::cout << " - b.check = " << b.check() << std::endl;
```

Comment: How do you measure? 0.002s can be a lot if the 1.23s is taken by the OS.

Comment: I measured how long each function took to run through. I would expect the move to be MUCH faster though. Or am I mistaken, that's where I'm not sure.

Comment: that doesn't answer his question: how did you measure it? I hope not with a chrono watch. Also posting the caller code could be useful

Comment: I posted the code relevant to the clock.

Comment: why is your move operator type `w3::DArray2d::DArray2d` and not `w3::DArray2d` ? second, your move operator does not first clean target there should be some `delete [] array` I suppose

Comment: Can you clean up your example?  Create a toy class that just has your `operator=` and the data and a way to populate it at the right size.  Then write a test harness.  It should total to a few dozen lines.  Confirm it still happens, and post that version?  There are to many unknowns above, and we do not want your entire project either.